# Insert into or update on duplicate key only if value is not in

Tags: mysql

I need to INSERT INTO or update on duplicate key a row only if a value is not present in any of the selected columns: the following query doesn't work. Can someone help me to find a solution?

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for basket_occasioni
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `basket_occasioni`;
CREATE TABLE `basket_occasioni` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occasione_0` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occasione_1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occasione_2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occasione_3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occasione_4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occasione_5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occasione_6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occasione_7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user` (`user`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of basket_occasioni
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `basket_occasioni` VALUES (8, 35, 0, 119, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122);
COMMIT;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

```
INSERT INTO basket_occasioni ( user, occasione_0, occasione_1, occasione_2, occasione_3, occasione_4, occasione_5, occasione_6, occasione_7 ) VALUES( 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 119 ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
occasione_0 = occasione_1,
occasione_1 = occasione_2,
occasione_2 = occasione_3,
occasione_3 = occasione_4,
occasione_4 = occasione_5,
occasione_5 = occasione_6,
occasione_6 = occasione_7,
occasione_7 = 122
WHERE 123 NOT IN ( occasione_0, occasione_1, occasione_2, occasione_3, occasione_4, occasione_5, occasione_6, occasione_7 )
```

Thanks

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2) alarm bells should start ringing.

Comment: @Strawberry, beside the poor schema and agreeing with you that using less enumerated columns is a better schema design, how the problem can be solved?

Comment: With lots of unions